# Auto discover projects in continous integration Tools

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, staging

We have a code base composed of many projects. Currently each time we add a project on SVN we must reconfigure CruiseControl to start build and test on such project.

I'm looking for a tool (better if open source) able to scan the SVN repository and find new projects by itself.
A project can be "a SVN folder containing trunk, tags, branches subfolders".

Even better if the tool supports multistaged continous integration and build on demand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, projects tend to be just different enough to require the build system to be set-up manually. However, you could probably use something like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) with some bash scripts to achieve what you're looking for; eg. if your SVN server has an HTML index of all the projects, you could set up a bash script to poll that page for changes then tell Jenkins to add a new project from a template.